# How can I access the output of ls in bash?

Tags: bash, shell, for-loop

I write the following script, expecting to print files in a directory. But it is just throwing the string "ls" on to screen.

What is the problem?

```
#!/bin/bash
for FILE in 'ls' 
do
   echo $FILE
done
```

Comment: You can do that without backticks, `for FILE in *;do echo $FILE;done` - or simply use `find`.

Comment: @user379203: If this answer helped you (and it looks right), please accept it (using the checkmark button).

Answer (score 9):

Wrong kind of quotes - you want:

```
for FILE in `ls`
```

Those are the backticks, not the single-quotes. Better still:

```
for FILE in $( ls )
```

You might also want to look at [this site](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ).

Comment: Please [Don't parse ls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)!  Use `for FILE in *` instead -- it's both faster and less error-prone.